# What is a class derived from a generic class and the generic type name is itself?

Tags: c#, grammar

I am reading the official example of unity, and I see there is a class named `Event`:

```
public abstract class Event : System.IComparable<Event>
{
...
}
```

And there is a generic class:

```
public abstract class Event<T> : Event where T : Event<T>
{
...
}
```

And some event derived from this like:

```
public class PlayerEnteredDeathZone : Simulation.Event<PlayerEnteredDeathZone>
{
...
}
```

In this sample, the class derived from a generic class but the 'T' is same as itself.

It confuses me, what is it?

Comment: Formally it's called _F-bound polymorphism_, but colloquially it's known as the _Curiously recurring template pattern_  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Comment: Easy mode: <T> is "any type", a dynamic object, so you can work with any type on that, as <T> can be filled with any type

Comment: @LeandroBardelli `T` is not `dynamic` - generics are still _static types_, there's no type-dynamism involved here. Also, the `where T : Event<T>` constraint means that `T` _cannot_ be "any type".

Comment: @Dai I know, I tried to explain to someone who is learning what is happening, that's why I'm doing a comment and not an answer, I know is wrong in definition, is just for make an idea. I'm from the idea that sometimes you have to choise between having right or teach, very hard thing.

Comment: @LeandroBardelli Aye, [teaching is hard - props](https://www.ted.com/talks/taylor_mali_what_teachers_make).